# Especialização múltiplas chave estrangeira

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, mysql

Olá, estou modelando um banco de dados e me deparei com o seguinte problema: eu tenho uma tabela chamada time, que é uma generalização para 4 tabelas especializadas, onde cada uma ira conter um id diferente, para saber a que time pertence cada jogador.Segue a imagem:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então quando eu gero o modelo lógico obtenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Três tabelas jogador, times... e patrocinador, e o problema esta na tabela patrocinador que recebe como chave estrangeira o id do time, eu não quero que o patrocinador patrocine um time 'n' e sim o "times+time1+time2..." todo time então não sei como fazer pois na hora de inserir no modelo físico não existe um único identificador que identifique todos os times, apenas os id de cada time:
time1 id = 1
time2 id = 2
time3 id = 3
time4 id = 4

Modelo físico:

```
CREATE TABLE times+time1+time2+time3+time4 (
nome Text,
id int PRIMARY KEY,
f1 Text,
f2 Text,
f3 Text,
f4 Text
)

CREATE TABLE patrocinador (
nome Text,
valor Text,
cnpj int PRIMARY KEY,
id Text,
id Text,
FOREIGN KEY( id) REFERENCES times+ time1+time2+time3+time4 (id)
)

CREATE TABLE jogador (
cpf int PRIMARY KEY,
sobrenome Text,
nome Text,
lider Text,
time Text,
id int,
FOREIGN KEY( id) REFERENCES times+ time1+time2+time3+time4 (id)
)
```

Se alguém sabe como resolver?
Desde já agradeço pela atenção!

Comment: só você retirar a chave estrangeira da tabela Patrocinadores, e adicionar uma estrangeira em times+time2+... com ID do patrocinador, desse modo vc tem um patrocinador para todos times.

Comment: Seu modelo já está quase correto. A tabela `times+time1+time2+time3+time4` tem uma chave primária para cada conjunto de 4 times. Quando você declara `times+time1+time2+time3+time4.id` como chave estrangeira de `patrocinador`, você une *um* patrocinador a *um* conjunto de times e, ao mesmo tempo, *um* conjunto de times a *vários* patrocinadores. O único erro que vejo é que, na tabela `patrocinador`, tem dois campos com nome `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Se você criar as tabelas dessa forma:

Adicionando a `FOREIGN KEY` de patrocinador na tabela de `TIMES`, você começa a ter uma relação `UM-PARA-UM` com patrocinador, ou seja, cada time terá um patrocinador.

```
CREATE TABLE times+time1+time2+time3+time4 (
nome Text,
id int PRIMARY KEY,
f1 Text,
f2 Text,
f3 Text,
f4 Text,
ID_PATROCINADOR int NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_TIMES FOREIGN KEY (ID_PATROCINADOR) REFERENCES patrocinador (id)
)
```

Caso você precise saber, qual `TIME` o `PATROCINADOR`está patrocinando, será necessário por uma `FOREIGN KEY`em patrocinador também, que será uma relação `UM-PARA-MUITOS`, ou seja, um patrocinador poderá patrocinar muitos times.

```
CREATE TABLE patrocinador (
nome Text,
valor Text,
cnpj int PRIMARY KEY,
id Text,
id Text,

FOREIGN KEY( id) REFERENCES times+ time1+time2+time3+time4 (id)
)

CREATE TABLE jogador (
cpf int PRIMARY KEY,
sobrenome Text,
nome Text,
lider Text,
time Text,
id int,
FOREIGN KEY( id) REFERENCES times+ time1+time2+time3+time4 (id)
)
```

Gostaria de te dar umas dicas quanto a forma de criar as `TABELAS`:

1. Quando criar os nomes das tabelas, tente por o nome da entidade no
   plural, por exemplo:  `TIMES, PATROCINADORES, JOGADORES,` etc.

Quando for criar as `CONSTRAINTS` tente por o nome delas para ficar fácil de você encontrar quando der algum problema, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE patrocinador (
nome Text,
valor Text,
cnpj int ,
id Text,
id Text,

CONSTRAINT PK_JOGADORES FOREIGN KEY (cnpj),
CONSTRAINT FK_PATROCINADOR_TIMES FOREIGN KEY( id) REFERENCES times+ time1+time2+time3+time4 (id)
)

CREATE TABLE jogador (
cpf int,
sobrenome Text,
nome Text,
lider Text,
time Text,
id int,
insira o código aqui
CONSTRAINT PK_JOGADORES PRIMARY KEY (ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_JOGADORES_TIMES FOREIGN KEY( id) REFERENCES times+ time1+time2+time3+time4 (id)
)
```

Criar `CONSTRAINT's` dando os nomes delas facilita na solução de erros futuros.